# Multiple selector not working with jQuery and find() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I use the multiple selector operator inside the find method it disregards the comma and reads all classes as one. I'm trying to disregard { and } in p tag elements.

HTML

```
<div class="coding">
<p style="padding-left: 30px;">
    <span style="color: #a30303;" data-mce-style="color: #a30303;">function</span> topStack ( a, b ) {
</p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;">return a * b;</p>

<p style="padding-left: 30px;">}</p>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('.coding p:not(:contains("{")) , .coding p:not(:contains("}"))').css('padding-left',"30px")
```

Comment: you tried it with one selector and it  worked ??

Comment: It did, the selector classes are correct. I ran through console and have use :not(:contains('') for all 3 elements isolating "{" "}" and "return" respectfully. The content('#content_ifr") is a reference to valid element in my DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use  `:not` twice like this

```
jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('.coding p:not(:contains("{")):not(:contains("}"))').css('padding-left',"30px");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly which looks to be using the CSS selector as an "and" operator. Would you have any insight as to why the comma didn't work in this case as it supposed to act a multiple selector operator in jQuery docs. BTW, just waiting for it to allow me to accept the answer.

Comment: @BrianEllis 1st glad it worked .. 2nd I really don't have a reference for multiselectors inside iframe .. but I used to use it with just one selector always .. I will search for that and I let you know .. Good Luck :-)